# Is there any way to see all elemental combos outside of combat?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I really love Specials Combo system in Xenoblade Chronicles 2, with all this bindings and elemental orbs. But it is hard to pick proper Blades loadout outside of combat for most optimized combos and bindings, as I can't actually find any information about those. Basically, the only way I can see combos is when I've already used first special in combo, and possible combos are displayed on top right corner.

So, is there actual way to see all combos, and their resulting bindings, in game? Or, at least, can I have link to some guide showing all possible combos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't really a way to view elemental combos in-game, but here is a guide:

[image: Chart of Elemental Combos and Seals]

<sub>[Guide by @ArchTalko on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ArchTalko/status/940732602490720256)</sub>

Comment: Well, this sucks. Game really misses good tutorials and info base, which was present in first game.

Comment: @lentinant It sure does. So it goes.