# What is a Blade Combo finisher?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

One of the requirements on my blade’s Affinity Chart is to “Perform a Blade Combo finisher.” It’s the last node on the chart, but I can’t figure out how to complete it.

What is a Blade Combo finisher? How do I perform one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Blade Combo finisher is the last Special Art performed in a [Blade/Elemental Combo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322836/27975).

There are two types of combos in Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Driver and Blade combos. Driver combos are performed using Driver Arts and require using Arts that inflict Break -> Topple -> Launch -> Smash statuses in that order. Blade combos are performed using Special Arts (moves initiated with the A button). You may also know them as “Elemental Combos”.

Comment: Use [this chart](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322836/27975) to figure out which combo you need to perform to get the right finisher.